# Differences in my US visa type during application

Tags: us-visa, b2visa

In the DS-160 form, I chose tourism/medical treatment B2 visa, but I chose Tourism/business visa B2 when I made the payment for the appointment. Does this mean the same thing or do I have to amend the DS-160 form?